# MySQL query with COUNT ON LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I've 2 table:

```
**Table A**              **Table B**
idTableA                 idTableB
Code                     idTableA
Description              Description
```

In Table B I can have more rows linked to table A.

So I need a query who return all table A's columns and COUNT(*) FROM Table B WHERE A.idTableA=B.idTableA

I tried this, but doesn't works:

```
SELECT A.*, B.COUNT(*) FROM TableA A LEFT JOIN TableB B ON A.idTableA = B.idTableA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
SELECT A.*, COUNT(B.idTableA)
FROM TableA A LEFT JOIN
     TableB B
     ON A.idTableA = B.idTableA
GROUP BY A.idTableA;
```

You seem unfamiliar with SQL.  You should understand `join` and `group by`.  These are fundamental concepts in the language.